# int variable output is not appearing in another package

Tags: java, import, package, integer, println

Hi I'm a freshman studying java and I'm currently encountering some problems regarding the packages and package import on where my int variable from another package is not showing up in the package where I imported it.

This is the package of int that I want to import to another package:

```
package StudentPackage;
import java.text.*;
public class Acadinfo {  
    
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");    
 int Studentn1, Studentn2;
 int q11, q12, q21, q22;
 int mt1, mt2;
 int f1, f2;
 int average, average2;

final void Acadinfo()
{
Studentn1 = 2468; Studentn2 = 13579;
q11 = 90; q12 = 90;
q21 = 80; q22 = 80;
mt1 = 100; mt2 = 85;
f1 = 95; f2 = 90;

int addaverage1 = q11 + q12 + mt1 + f1;
average = addaverage1 / 4;

int addaverage2 = q21 + q22 + mt2 + f2;
average2 = addaverage2 / 4;
}
public final void displayEducDetails1()
{    
System.out.println("STUDENT EDUCATIONAL DETAILS");
System.out.println("Student Number: " + Studentn1);
System.out.println("Student Grade Average: " + df.format(average));
System.out.println("Student Attendance: 100%");
}

public final void displayEducDetails2()
{    
System.out.println("STUDENT EDUCATIONAL DETAILS");
System.out.println("Student Number: " + Studentn2);
System.out.println("Student Grade Average: " + df.format(average2));
System.out.println("Student Attendance: 100%");
}

}
```

Here is the main package where I want the int to appear:

```
package MainPackage;
import StudentPackage.*;
public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Acadinfo ai = new Acadinfo();
    
    ai.displayEducDetails1();
    System.out.println();
    ai.displayEducDetails2();
    }
    
}
```

but the output appears like this:

```
STUDENT EDUCATIONAL DETAILS
Student Number: 0
Student Grade Average: .00
Student Attendance: 100%

STUDENT EDUCATIONAL DETAILS
Student Number: 0
Student Grade Average: .00
Student Attendance: 100%
```

I'd like to know where I went wrong and what are the mistakes that I did here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[youngblood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15868092/youngblood) you have defined your constructor as `final void Acadinfo(){}` which is not visible by `MainProgram` make it `public Acadinfo()`. you can not assign return types to a constructor as this will make compiler think as a new method instead of a constructor.

problem:

```
final void Acadinfo()
{
Studentn1 = 2468; Studentn2 = 13579;
q11 = 90; q12 = 90;
q21 = 80; q22 = 80;
mt1 = 100; mt2 = 85;
f1 = 95; f2 = 90;

int addaverage1 = q11 + q12 + mt1 + f1;
average = addaverage1 / 4;

int addaverage2 = q21 + q22 + mt2 + f2;
average2 = addaverage2 / 4;
}
```

Solution:

```
public Acadinfo()
{
Studentn1 = 2468; Studentn2 = 13579;
q11 = 90; q12 = 90;
q21 = 80; q22 = 80;
mt1 = 100; mt2 = 85;
f1 = 95; f2 = 90;

int addaverage1 = q11 + q12 + mt1 + f1;
average = addaverage1 / 4;

int addaverage2 = q21 + q22 + mt2 + f2;
average2 = addaverage2 / 4;
}
```